# How do I map through this (file) - React MongoDB Javascript

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFhwa.png)[I have this saved in a useState  saved (just console.logged it) and would like to map it. Somehow my map function doesn't seem to work. Maybe it is the wrong file format or path?

`{result.data.data.map((e) => { return (<> <li>{e.charity}</li> </> )})}`

Answer (score 0):

You should map like this :

```
{result.data.data.map(user => <li> {user.charity} </li>)}
```

`user` here it each item of your array

Comment: This is essentially the same thing that OP already has, minus some unecessary punctuation.  Not sure it solves their issue, but it is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your map function.  What I assume is happening is you are attempting to map over this array before `result` becomes available.  If you are making an asynchronous api call to receive this data, then the code will continue executing while waiting for the `result`.

I can't be sure what the rest of your code looks like, but an easy way to fix this is to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to call your map.

Something like this:

```
{result?.data.data.map((e) => { return (<> <li>{e.charity}</li> </> )})}
```

The addition of the question mark will check if `result` has any value, and will gracefully exit the execution without throwing an error.  Then when the result becomes available, then react will execute the result map.

All this is assuming you are setting up the rest of your component correctly.  If this doesn't solve your issue, please update your question to include more *relevant* code.